# getting error: appium & commnad not found on MAC

Tags: ios, macos, appium

I have configured appium and node using following steps:

```
brew install node 
brew link node 
npm install -g appium@1.4.11
npm install wd
```

Now when i provide "appium &", it says command not found. Please help me in starting the appium server.

Comment: If you want to run Appium via an npm install  you will need node.js and npm 0.10 or greater (use n or brew install node to install Node.js. Make sure you have not installed Node or Appium with sudo

Comment: npm install -g appium.. install appium

Comment: so shall i uninstall everything and do installations again? and instead of brew install node ,type brew install node.js??

Comment: you have asked the same question twice. Please delete the other one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815784/getting-error-appium-commnad-not-found-on-mac

Comment: i have npm version 2.14.1 and node version 4.1.1 and have installed using brew install node and not used sudo..still getting command not found error..please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command:

```
npm install -g appium --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

Answer (score 0):

1-> ln -fs /Users//.npm-global/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js /usr/local/bin/appium

2-> chmod +x /usr/local/bin/appium

followed above steps  worked for me

Answer (score -1):

This problem arises when your appium is not installed by npm, try uninstall the appium then reinstall it using `npm install -g appium`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).